# Return the min value in array with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please, my SQL query gives me this array as result.

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array (
      [0] => Array ( [idConsultant] => 291 [number] => 3 ) 
   ) 
   [1] => Array (
      [0] => Array ( [idConsultant] => 292 [number] => 2 ) 
   ) 
   [2] => Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( [idConsultant] => 293 [number] => 1 ) 
   )
)
```

I just need to return IdConsultant where the number is min.

In this case, the return result will be 293.

Thank!!!

Comment: Can you share your SQL query too? I think one could try and filter the minimum idConsultant at the database level itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure PHP option is -

To extract all ID columns use -

```
$ids = array_column($resultsArray, 'idConsultant');
```

Use Ids array in the `min` function :-

```
$minId = min($ids);

echo "Minimum Id : ".$minId;
```

Hope this helps.